# Bitwise subtraction from .All

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I have the following code, and am wondering if there's a way to write the bitwise operator in the last section (Copy Files Only) to include both setting it to the All value and then removing the other two on a single line.

```
private void cbInstallType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbInstallType.Text == "Full Install")
        {
            eventFlags = GBFEvents.All;
        }

        else if (cbInstallType.Text == "DB Only")
        {
            eventFlags = (GBFEvents.InitGBFSQL | GBFEvents.PerformDatabaseUpdate);
        }

        else if (cbInstallType.Text == "Copy Files Only")
        {
            eventFlags = GBFEvents.All;
            eventFlags &= ~(GBFEvents.InitGBFSQL | GBFEvents.PerformDatabaseUpdate);
        }
    }
```

GBFEvents is defined thusly:

```
    public enum GBFEvents
{
    NONE                        =       0,
    InitGBFSQL                  =       1 << 0,
    ServiceIISControlDown       =       1 << 1,
    SetWebConfigValues          =       1 << 2,
    ReadFilelists               =       1 << 3,
    CopyFiles                   =       1 << 4,
    FixWebConfigValues          =       1 << 5,
    BuildAppPaths               =       1 << 6,
    PerformDatabaseUpdate       =       1 << 7,
    ServiceIISControlUp         =       1 << 8,
    All                         =    ~(-1 << 9)
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you understand what `&=` is doing?

Comment: how is `GBFEvents` defined?

Comment: So if you add something new to `GBFEvents` that isn't file copying related, this will still do it when "Copy Files Only" is selected? This may be "cleverer" than listing each copy flag individually, but are you sure it's the most *readable*?

Comment: @Chris - I do.  And it works fine.  Maybe this is just for science, but I like concise code, and when it comes to bitwise operators, they're either readable or not, depending solely on the reader rather than the operation.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - that is correct.  This is for building out test VMs.  By default there's a list of tasks that occur that does the file copy and the DB update.  Sometimes you may only need to do one or the other.  The core processes haven't changed in 15 years, so I don't expect anything new.  It's either everything, only DB-related stuff, or only non-DB related stuff (which also turns down IIS and services before copying, parses file lists and such).

Comment: @DanielA.White - updated the initial post with the enum.

Comment: @Chris - I didn't say I had a problem.  I'm asking a question with the intent of gaining knowledge.  Didn't realize that the Q&A nature of SE required some dire need aside from having a topical question.  I have some basic knowledge of bitwise operators, and was interested to see if there was some shorthand version of those two lines.  That's it.

Comment: @JesseWilliams: Well I've given an answer since it seemed easier than trying to work out why you couldn't do it. The reason I was asking the question is because my answer seemed pretty trivial assuming you knew what `&=` did. I realised though that it was easier to just give you the info and let you worry about what was new to you and where your problem in doing it yourself was. :)

Comment: @Chris - much appreciated.  As noted to your answer, overthinking and lack of caffeination was making this trivial task more complex than necessary. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing it to a single line is a pretty simple case of just expanding what things do. So going step by step:

```
var eventFlags = GBFEvents.All;
eventFlags &= ~(GBFEvents.InitGBFSQL | GBFEvents.PerformDatabaseUpdate);
```

If we expand the `&=` we get:

```
var eventFlags = GBFEvents.All;
eventFlags = eventFlags & ~(GBFEvents.InitGBFSQL | GBFEvents.PerformDatabaseUpdate);
```

If we then inline the use of eventFlags in the second line we get:

```
var eventFlags = GBFEvents.All & ~(GBFEvents.InitGBFSQL | GBFEvents.PerformDatabaseUpdate);
```

Comment: Oh duh - thanks.  I was overthinking it considerably.  I was trying to double-set the value (which of course, isn't an option).  /sigh it's early and I need more coffee...

Answer (score 3):

I know you've already got an acceptable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52893245/15498) for your question, but I'd still prefer something like this in your `enum`:

```
public enum GBFEvents
{
    NONE = 0,
    InitGBFSQL = 1 << 0,
    ServiceIISControlDown = 1 << 1,
    SetWebConfigValues = 1 << 2,
    ReadFilelists = 1 << 3,
    CopyFiles = 1 << 4,
    FixWebConfigValues = 1 << 5,
    BuildAppPaths = 1 << 6,
    PerformDatabaseUpdate = 1 << 7,
    ServiceIISControlUp = 1 << 8,

    /* Helpers */

    AllDBEvents = InitGBFSQL | PerformDatabaseUpdate,
    AllServiceEvents = ServiceIISControlDown | ServiceIISControlUp,
    AllConfigEvents = SetWebConfigValues | FixWebConfigValues,
    AllFileEvents = ReadFilelists | CopyFiles | BuildAppPaths,
    All = AllDBEvents | AllServiceEvents | AllConfigEvents | AllFileEvents
}
```

(I may have mischaracterized `BuildAppPaths`, you may consider it more `Config` related, as an example)

And then your code here would be:

```
eventFlags = AllServiceEvents | AllConfigEvents | AllFileEvents;
```

(And the other path would just use `AllDbEvents`)

This, to me, makes it clearer on reading that "Copy Files Only" isn't just copying files whilst not having to have tonnes of options `|`ed together on that line. And these helper values in your `enum` may be reusable in other areas too.

The main idea is to make the "named groups" of events explicit in your enum rather than having to correctly combine them in other parts of your code.

Comment: Ok, I did not know you could do that.  That's actually pretty slick!  Thank you for this answer.  It's not likely what I'll use for this particular thing, but this would actually help on another project I have.